# getting .text() of children elements from jQuery()

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm having trouble to get the proper formatted texts of each child elements, either as an Array or in as text.

I had tried

```
var name= jQuery(".childOne").text();
var number = jQuery(".childTwo").text();
```

but it joins all the name/number text in name and number.

HTML is:

```html
<span class="parent"><span class="childOne">David</span><span class="childTwo">541</span></span>
<span class="parent"><span class="childOne">Gruce</span><span class="childTwo">162</span></span>
<span class="parent"><span class="childOne">Proman</span><span class="childTwo">743</span></span>
```

and I need to generate output in multi-dim-array so that each child-element's-text can be figured out properly.

Preferred output can be in array or in any form.

```
Array
(
    0 = > array (
            0 => "David",
            1 => "541"
        ),
        
    1 = > array (
            0 => "Gruce",
            1 => "162"
        ),
        
    2 = > array (
            0 => "Proman",
            1 => "743"
        )
)
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

try this:

```
var data = [];

$('span.parent').each(function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    data.push({
        'name' : $this.find('span.childOne').text(),
        'number' : $this.find('span.childTwo').text()
    });
});
```

BTW: jQuery uses the Sizzle selctor engine. You should define the element type before the class, like `span.parent`. This is much more faster.

Comment: Another thing: If you access $(this) in the current scope more than once, you should use a seperate variable: like var $this. So, jQuery must not wrap the element twice, or more.

Comment: @OpenCode: If you won't use the result literal, you can replace the push statement with the following code: data.push([$this.find('span.childOne').text(), $this.find('span.childTwo').text()]);

Answer (score 3):

If this is a fixed structure, you can do:

```
var data = [];

$('.parent').each(function() {
    data.push({
        'name': $(this).children('.childOne').text(),
        'number': $(this).children('.childTwo').text()
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

I have made a working [example](http://jsfiddle.net/KSZdN/1/)

```
var array= [];


$('.parent').each(function(index) {
   array.push({
        'name': $(this).children('.childOne').text(),
        'number': $(this).children('.childTwo').text()
    });
  });
alert(array[0].name);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.parent').each(function(index) {
     alert($(this).find('.childOne').text());
     alert($(this).find('.childTwo').text());
  });
```

After you can put them into an array